# How to read and delete string between specific characters from file in c++

Tags: c++, string, text-files

Hello I want to read and delete some part between /* and (asterisk here)*/. There are multiple lines between /*(asterisk here) and */. So I think I have to read all the lines from text file and check for them. It is easy to delete strings on single line with substr() method in while loop. Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: From a file with C++ code (ide problem) or with a text file using C++ (programming)?

Comment: with a text file using C++ programming

Comment: The cleanest is to load the entire file in memory, remove the comments, then write the result back to the file.

Comment: This is the part which I couldn't do. I opened the file, got the all lines with while loop but I couldn't remove multiple lines between /* and */

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read all content of your file into a string, like:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cerrno>
#include <iostream>

std::string contents;
std::ifstream in("c:\\file.txt", std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);
if (in) {    
    in.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
    contents.resize(in.tellg());
    in.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
    in.read(&contents[0], contents.size());
    in.close();
}
```

Then, using regular expression, you can extract all content between /* and */:

```
#include <regex>

std::smatch m;
std::regex e ("(?:/\\*(?:[^*]|(?:\\*+[^*/]))*\\*+/)|(?://.*)");

while (std::regex_search (contents, m, e)) {
    for (auto x : m) {
        std::cout << x << std::endl;
    }
    contents = m.suffix().str();
}
```

For each match, the content between /* and */ was set in variable m, then you can manipulate the content of it.

Reading a file like this:

> /*
>
> Created by Felipe Cardoso on 07/02/14.
>
> Copyright (c) 2014 MobileCard. All rights reserved.
>
> */
>
> First line content
>
> Second line content
>
> /* Function description ... */
>
> End of file

The result is:

[image: match result]

Answer (score 1):

You may use shell process to help you:

> ```
> cat example.c | tr -d "/\*.*\*/" > new_example.c
> ```